# Listing all point items in polygon?

Tags: qgis-3

I'm trying to get a list of all points (from a point layer) that can be found in a unique rectangle polygon.

Input layer 1: points (address data)
Input layer 2: rectangle polygon layer (created with research tools, create grid)

I used the grid to create an atlas and now my goal is, to get different lists, that show me what page contains what addresses.

As output I need a list with all addresses and an "extra column" that shows me on what atlas page I can find each address. So that I can take the right page when someone gives me an address to find.

If there is a function to analyse that, I'm unable to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Print Composer you can add a table.  When you select your table, select the tab 'item properties'.  There (under feature filtering) check *show only features intersecting atlas feature*.

[image]

For creating  a **'connection' between your points**, you can choose for a fixed solution or a dynamic solution.

**Fixed solution**

- in the processing toolbox (ctrl + alt + t) search for 'join attributes by location'
- set your points-layer as *target vector layer*
- set your rectangle-layer as *join vector layer*
- set intersect as geometric predicate
- run the algorithm

**Dynamic solution**

- add a virtual layer (Layer > Add layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer)
- import your 2 layers
- add following SQL:

  ```
  select pt.attr1, pt.attr2, pt.attr3, pg.attrA, pg.attrB 
  from point pt
  left join polygon pg on st_intersects(pt.geometry, pg.geometry)
  ```

Change point and polygon to your appropriate layer names.

Comment: thank you very much! thats just not 100% what i need... 

i need a sort of connection with the polygon and the point layer... i need a list, with all the adresses and (maybe as an extra field) the id of the polygon in which the adress is. so that i can choose the right atlas page when i get the adress information

Comment: then you have to clarify your question, because what you tell here is not what you asked.

Comment: @darius, for what you ask, you need sql.  I will change my answer

Comment: @darius, does the connection has to be dynamic?

Comment: no - i prepare everything for one project and at the end, after i produced my atlas, i want to output the adress/page information

Comment: Thank you so much! join attributes by location is exactly what i wanted!!!